# TCA override on showItem when sys_language_uid != 0

Tags: php, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-10.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm updating a TYPO3 v8.7 to TYPO3 10.4 LTS

In the TCA we have a pageType with a `showitem` of our choice. In v8 we used the following to have a custom view for a translated page eg. `pages_language_overlay`

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types'][$doktype] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types'][$doktype],
    [
        'showitem' => '
                         myCustomShowItemString
                '
    ]
);
```

**Question:** What would be the correct way to get have this behaviour again since pages_language_overlay does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCA - file which has to be loaded after custom fields

```
$disableOnLanguageOverlay = [
    'my_tca_field',
    'my_tca_field',
];

foreach ($disableOnLanguageOverlay as $field) {
    if (isset($GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns'][$field])) {
        $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns'][$field] = array_merge($GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns'][$field], ['l10n_mode' => 'exclude']);
    }
}
```

And for Typoscript

```
[siteLanguage("languageId") != 0]
    TCEFORM {
        pages {
            myField {
                disabled = 0
            }
        }
    }
[global]
```

Solved above

Answer (score 2):

as the translated `pages`records also are `pages` records you need this configuration for the table `pages`.

either you have it already, as your new doktype behaves the same for each language

or you need a special handling if `sys_language_uid` is not `0`.
Then you probably need [display conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/Columns/Index.html#displaycond) for those fields which behave different depending on `sys_language_uid` (this one visible, others invisible?)